# SonarQube Docker Installation CorruptIndexException: checksum failed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, sonarqube

I'm trying to create docker container with SonarQube inside it, but I get this error while composing for the first time:

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.lucene.index.CorruptIndexException: checksum failed (hardware problem?) : expected=f736ed01 actual=298dcde2 (resource=BufferedChecksumIndexInput(NIOFSIndexInput(path="/opt/sonarqube/data/es7/nodes/0/_state/_7w.fdt")))
```

I tried installing it on a fresh instance with fresh docker installation, I even tried to install it on a different server to rule out hardware failure, and I still get the same error. What could be the cause of it?

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube:community
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      SONAR_JDBC_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_USERNAME: sonar
      SONAR_JDBC_PASSWORD: sonar
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - sonarqube_logs:/opt/sonarqube/logs
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
  db:
    image: postgres:12
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: sonar
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: sonar
    volumes:
      - postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql
      - postgresql_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data

volumes:
  sonarqube_data:
  sonarqube_extensions:
  sonarqube_logs:
  postgresql:
  postgresql_data:
```

Comment: I think showing us the dockerfile might help since you gave no real details here

Comment: Had the same issue with a recent update. After attempting many things (fresh reinstall / disk health check / RAM health check), I ended up redeploying a previous version (sonarqube:9.2.4-community) and it worked. I can't explain why new version is throwing this error though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Updated answer (august 2022)

Problem is fixed in the official v9.6 image.

### Updated answer (june 2022)

I was able to build a working image by using this Dockerfile:

```
FROM sonarqube:community
USER root
RUN apk add --no-cache --upgrade 'zlib>=1.2.12-r1';
USER sonarqube
```

(credits to [this Github comment](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/issues/544#issuecomment-1141904093))

### Original answer (april 2022)

As stated in [this issue](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/issues/544) from the Docker-Sonarqube repository:

This bug appeared when the alpine base image has been updated to 3.14.5+. So you have two choices for now:

- Either rollback Sonarqube 9.2.4 (prior versions have the Log4J vulnerability)
- Re-build the latest Sonarqube image yourself with alpine version set to 3.14.3 (as explained in [this comment](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/issues/544#issuecomment-1092517489))

Answer (score 1):

Solved it by using `image: sonarqube:9.2.4-developer`

Answer (score 0):

If its running docker inside a vm, try to enable nested virtualization for the vm.

Link to understand nested virt (https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/nested-virtualization/overview)